# Display JSON Objects vertically on a web page using table/flexboxes/divs and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, flexbox

I have a JSON with multiple products. All these products are defined by data. I would like to loop through this JSON and place these products side by side on a web page to compare them together. I think of a structure first organized in columns and then rows :

[image]

So far I can do this easily with HTML divs and flexboxes. Something like :

```
<div style="display:flex">
     <div id="Sidebar">
          <div class="Data_1">...</div>
          <div class="Data_2">...</div>
          <div class="Data_3">...</div>
          <div class="Data_4">...</div>
          ...
     </div>
     <div id="Product_A">
          <div class="Data_1">...</div>
          <div class="Data_2">...</div>
          <div class="Data_3">...</div>
          <div class="Data_4">...</div>
          ...
     </div>
     <div id="Product_B">
          <div class="Data_1">...</div>
          <div class="Data_2">...</div>
          <div class="Data_3">...</div>
          <div class="Data_4">...</div>
          ...
     </div>
     <div id="Product_C">
          <div class="Data_1">...</div>
          <div class="Data_2">...</div>
          <div class="Data_3">...</div>
          <div class="Data_4">...</div>
          ...
     </div>
</div>
```

But, if one of the product features contains a long string, I would like the height of all adjacent cells of the other products and the sidebar to fit also in height.

[image]

I know I can achieve a such structure with an HTML table, but it's not convenient to dynamically add/remove products or make them draggable as tables are first organized in rows. I would like to be able to add products, remove products, drag them, filter them, sort them... I think that a table  structure is not suitable.

[image]

My questions :

- If using tables, is there a way to first organize a table in columns then rows?
- If using divs or flexboxes, how can I align all the product lines in height?
- Any other good idea to structure such content or use javascript to achieve this easily?

Comment: its tabular data and as such a table is appropriate. Your design would be easily solvable with colgroups. However, the creating and filling of a table with data needs to be done either backend with a templating language such as PHP or frontend with JS (need to fetch a JSON or use a similar technique).

Comment: it's all about how you organize your data. you may need to do it on the client side if you don't control the api. but a matrix would work here and draw out a css-grid.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with using max-height and iterate products in div or ul>li.
Show code to get more help.

Comment: You mean iterating, for example, through all "Data 3" product divs with javascript, find the max height of all these divs and apply this value to all "Data 3" divs ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Probably put a min-height on the product container and then iterate through your json with something like.

```
products.map(product => 
  <div>
    <span> product.name </span>
  </div>
```

)

The product container div should adapt its own contents if the json data is longer than what you are waiting.

Comment: Yes, but I want the related DIVs of the other products being adapted as well. Not only the DIV with the long data.